# clerk - middleware error when I try to deploy with vercel in nextjs project

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel, clerk

I got the following errors while trying to deploy in Vercel, but I had already placed the secret key it asked me for in my application as it said. I was not getting such an error a few deployments ago.

what could be the reason?

these are the errors I get;

```
[GET] [middleware: "middleware"] / reason=EDGE_FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED, status=500, user_error=true
```

--

```
Error: Missing Clerk Secret Key or API Key. Go to https://dashboard.clerk.com and get your key for your instance.
at (node_modules/@clerk/backend/dist/esm/index.js:697:10)
at (node_modules/@clerk/backend/dist/esm/index.js:2767:2)
at (node_modules/@clerk/backend/dist/esm/index.js:2874:11)
at (node_modules/@clerk/nextjs/dist/esm/server/authenticateRequest.js:16:27)
at (node_modules/@clerk/nextjs/dist/esm/server/authMiddleware.js:64:31)
at (node_modules/next/dist/esm/server/web/adapter.js:157:15)
```

--

and some files;

```
import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";
export default authMiddleware({
  publicRoutes: ["/","/board"],
});
 
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};
```

--

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_blablabblablablablablablablabla
CLERK_SECRET_KEY=sk_test_blablablablablablablablblablabla
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_IN_URL=/sign-in
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_UP_URL=/sign-up
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_IN_URL=/
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_UP_URL=/
```